# jquery children() selector not selecting proper element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am using jquery to try to select an item within a simple table. When I call something like

```
$('.broadcast_item_even').mouseover(function(event) {

    //SET TR GLOW EFFECT
    $(this).attr('class', 'broadcast_item_hover');

    //ALERT THE VALUE 
    alert( $(this).children(2).html());

});
```

on this table object

```
<table style="color: rgb(0, 0, 255);" id="Table1">  
    <tbody>
        <tr class="broadcast_item_even">
            <td>
                <img height="50px" width="50px" alt="user avatar" src="../../Avatar/default-user.jpg">

            </td>
            <td>                 
                jimbo60
            </td>

            <td>
                10.8 miles
            </td>

        </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

the result prints

```
<img height="50px" width="50px" alt="user avatar" src="../../Avatar/default-user.jpg">
```

and not

```
10.8 miles
```

which is what I am expecting. Does anyone have an idea as to why this might be occurring? If so, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the third child you need [`:eq(2)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) or [`.eq(2)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), like this:

```
$(this).children().eq(2).html()
//or:
$(this).children(":eq(2)").html()
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/jdZme/).  The [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) function takes a *selector*, not an index.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$(this).children('td:last').html()`

Answer (score 0):

You cal also use following code to get the text of third td.

> alert($(this).find("td").eq(2).html());